# Initialize variables before having anyone enter the web app

Tags: asp.net

How can I initialize variables before my Web Application starts? I want to have, for example an `Application` type, to count number of logged in users in my website (it's an example, I have more variables that need initialization). How can I perform that?

It could be very useful if there was some event that would be called at the start of the Web App. I thought that I could check in each `Page_Load` event if a certain `Session` called, e.g `Session["Started"]` is null, and if it, redirect to an `.aspx` page for initialization. Or, even better, have a class called, e.g `MyPage` which inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page` and have her constructor get a function as an argument, which will be called after the initialization of the base class `Page_Load`.

Maybe I'm just bothering, is there any built-in event called that I can overwrite to initialize everything I want in the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Global.asax` file for this. In particular you can use the `Application_Start`, `Session_Start`, `Session_End` events.

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

[Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/) for more informations.